# Pass expression to directive for transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which uses a template to generate a typeahead in a form with associated label and css classes.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': hasSuccess(field),
                                    'has-error'  : hasError(field) }">
<label class="control-label" for="{{ field }}">
    {{ label }}
</label>
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       ng-model="model"
       name="{{ field }}"
       id="{{ field }}"
       typeahead="{{ items }}"
       required>
</div>
```

This is created using the following markup:

```
<fe-ta model='model.state2' label='State' items='s in states'></fe-ta>
```

The problem is the expression passed to `items`. I get the following exception:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'in' is an unexpected token at column 3 of the expression \
 [s in states] starting at [in states].
```

My directive takes `items` in its isolate scope as an expression `&`

```
 .directive('feTa', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: ['^form', '^feForm'],
      scope: {
          model: '=',
          label: '@',
          items: '&
      },
      templateUrl: 'typeahead.tmpl.html',
      replace: true,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
          var feFormController = controllers[1];

          scope.field = attrs.model.substring(attrs.model.indexOf('.') + 1);
          scope.hasSuccess = feFormController.hasSuccess;
          scope.hasError = feFormController.hasError;
      }
    };    
  });
```

**How can I pass an expression to my directive?**

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ivvJzUOxKGsAqqgzDPl0?p=preview

Comment: Just a conjecture, but I think you might be incorrectly assuming that the `... in ...` syntax available in built-in directives like `ng-repeat` and `ng-options` works the same way elsewhere. For example, if you look around line 248 in [`ngRepeat.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js) you'll see that `ng-repeat` implements its own processing for a string expression in the format `... in ...`.

Comment: Hmm - I think you may be right! :(